# Canceling android ads after payment

Tags: android, google-play, ads, in-app-billing

Some time ago i saw an app on the market which had an option of "no initial fee for the app, but pay a small fee after you downloaded it, and the ads will disappear". I'm a beginner at this with no current apps in my portfolio, can anyone tell me how that can be made possible? Basically how it works. Do you have to set up a separate billing method, or you can use the android market billing system and when he pays he can then downloads an update of the app which cancels the ads ?!?!

I was unable to find anything related on the web, so if anyone can explain, i'd be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: This is most likely realized using [In-app billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html). This way the app can query whether the "full version" article has been purchased from the server and hide the ads accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use in-app billing and once the payment have been verified you can basically hide the ad (set its visibility to GONE).
example:

```
if(paid) {
 ad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that i would know how to do but how would my app know if he/she paid or not. Does the user download an update or ... ?? In this case for instance, the variable 'paid' where would that get initialized? :)

Comment: Google provides you a pretty http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html